# How do I format an array with 1000 random numbers from 10-99?

Tags: arrays, random, numbers

This works to print the numbers on one line, but I want to format the array so that there are 20 numbers per row. How would I go about doing this?

```
Random r = new Random();

int[] myArray = new int[1000];        
for (int counter = 0; counter < myArray.length; counter++) {
    int store = 10 + r.nextInt(89);
    myArray[counter] = store;
    System.out.print(myArray[counter]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Random r = new Random();

int[] myArray = new int[1000];        
for (int counter = 0; counter < myArray.length; counter++) {
    int store = 10 + r.nextInt(89);
    myArray[counter] = store;
    if(counter != 0 && counter % 20 == 0)
        System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print(myArray[counter] + " ");
}
```